# Can I stream a video with HTML5?

Tags: streaming, html5-video

I'm making a web page in html5 that plays videos, but my source of videos is in .ts format, and I know  tag of html5 doens't support this. So what I need to know is if there's a way to stream the video while I'm converting the .ts file to a .mp4 or .webm file. The need to do this simultaneously is the fact that the video could have hours of duration and would take to much time to wait the .ts to convert and I can't change the format of the videos of my source. Since the main target is to support for chrome, I can't use HLS, what would be great to me.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the embedded html5 tags for your video playback, so your choices are either 1. converting them to mp4 or webm, or 2. you could use a different media player (flowplayer or jwplayer are good examples for what you're looking to do) and embed them directly into your page.